# Powershell script launched from logon script not working

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a powershell script that searches a users C drive for a certain file extension, and then writes a file to a network share if it finds one. The script is launched from the last line of a logon script that reads like this:

`powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -windowstyle hidden -file "\\servername\Path\To\File.ps1"`

And my powershell script looks like this:

```
$hostname = HostName

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\*.* -Filter $file -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction 
SilentlyContinue | Out-File \\servername\Path\To\Results\$hostname\file.txt

If ((Get-Content "\\servername\Path\To\Results\$hostname\file.txt") -eq $Null) {

    Remove-Item \\servername\Path\To\Results\$hostname\file.txt
}
Exit
```

The script runs perfectly fine on my machine even when I load it from the network share but whenever another computer runs it, it never produces an Out File. And I don't think it is even searching.

What am I doing wrong? I thought it was execution policy, but I've set the logon script to bypass it. I don't understand why it isn't working.

[edit]
I've now got the script working sometimes on Windows 10 machines. But it doesn't work at all on Windows 7. I've even tried running

`Get-ChildItem C:\*.pst -Recurse`

directly from a powershell command prompt, and it just fails silently and doesn't search for anything. Isn't Get-ChildItem a powershell 1 command?

Comment: Why do you write the file and then immediately remove it?

Comment: It will only remove the file if the file is empty. Because the window is hidden and the script is otherwise invisible to the user, I needed some way to check if the script was actually working. So while Get-ChildItem is searching, a txt file appears in the folder. Then if nothing was written to the file, it gets deleted. 

So the only txt files that will be left in that folder are the users that have the file I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello. If you do like this: Get-ChildItem -Path C:*.* -Filter $file
>   -Recurse -Force the text file output will be enough to weigh.
>   You can try to check the access to the network folder for the current
>   user:if access explicitly set, and write access exists, then you can
>   record a file with the content. Otherwise, it can create folder test
>   on the local machine which will create the file, indicating that there
>   is no access. How is this way:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force| Out-Null

$user = [System.Environment]::UserName

$hostname = [System.Environment]::MachineName

try {
$accs = Get-ACL -Path "\\server\sharedfolder\Results\" 

foreach ($access in $accs) {

$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{

Access = $accs.Access

}

$obj1 = $obj | select -ExpandProperty Access

for ($i = 0 ; $i -le $obj1.Count ; $i ++ )

{

if (!($obj1[$i].IdentityReference  -like "*Users*" -or $obj1[$i].IdentityReference -like "*$user*")) {

if (!(Test-Path "c:\test")) {

md c:\test



$s = "user access from group" 

$s | out-file C:\test\ErrInfo.csv

}

else {

$s = "user access from group" 

$s | out-file C:\test\ErrInfo.csv

}

}

if ($obj1[$i].IdentityReference  -like "*Users*" -or $obj1[$i].IdentityReference -like "*$user*") {

if ($obj1[$i].FileSystemRights -like "*ReadAndExecute*")

{

if (!(Test-Path "c:\test")) {

md c:\test

$s = "Premission only ReadAndExecute" 

$s | out-file C:\test\ErrInfo_rex.csv

}

else {

$s = "Premission only ReadAndExecute" 

$s | out-file C:\test\ErrInfo_rex.csv

}

}

if ($obj1[$i].FileSystemRights -like "*FullControl*" -and $obj1[$i].AccessControlType -like "*Allow*" -or $obj1[$i].FileSystemRights -like "*Modify*" -and $obj1[$i].AccessControlType -like "*Allow*")

{

if (!(Test-Path "\\server\sharedfolder\Results\$hostname"))

{

md "\\server\sharedfolder\Results\$hostname" 

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\testpatch\*.* -Filter $file -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-File "\\server\sharedfolder\Results\$hostname\file.txt"


}

else {



Get-ChildItem -Path C:\testpatch\*.* -Filter $file -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-File "\\server\sharedfolder\Results\$hostname\file.txt"


}


}

}


}

}
}

catch {

if (!(Test-Path "c:\test")) {

md c:\test

$s = "--NoAccess--" 

$s | out-file C:\test\ErrInfo_noaccess.csv

}

else {

$s = "--NoAccess--" 

$s | out-file C:\test\ErrInfo_noaccess.csv

}

}
```

Or you can do something like this (whiteout EXIT):

```
 Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force| Out-Null

$hostname = [System.Environment]::MachineName

if (!(Test-Path "\\server\sharedfolder\Results\$hostname")) {

md "\\server\sharedfolder\Results\$hostname" | Out-Null

If ((Get-ChildItem -Path C:\test\*.* -Filter $file -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count  -ne "0") {

   Get-ChildItem -Path C:\test\*.* -Filter $file -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-File "\\server\sharedfolder\Results\$hostname\file.txt"
}

}

elseif (Test-Path "\\server\sharedfolder\Results\$hostname") {

If ((Get-ChildItem -Path C:\test\*.* -Filter $file -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count  -ne "0") {

   Get-ChildItem -Path C:\test\*.* -Filter $file -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-File "\\server\sharedfolder\Results\$hostname\file.txt"
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try this tomorrow.

I don't need to check network access because I know everyone has access to this folder. It is on a public network share that everyone in the company has read/write access to.

Comment: @MustardFacial Do they have delete access, though?

Comment: Everyone has Full Control to the shared drive